# How do i set the initial size of the table when using paging?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Im using the paging plugin to the tablesorter and im wondering how do i pass the initial size of the table?

If my table is 8 rows long, and i want it to be only show 2 when the page is first visited, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging thru the .js file i found that you could set size when you construct it :D default is 10.

os

```
.tablesorterPager({size: 2, container: $("#pager")});
```

would do the trick :D